# Spring Tool Suite + Infinitest preference page error

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite, infinitest

STS 4.14.0.RELEASE with Infinitest 5.2 throws an error on accessing the Infinitest preferences page:

Unable to create the selected preference page.
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Comment: It would be useful to post the stack trace here in order to find out what the problem might be. You might also want to try to install Infinitest 5.2 into a plain Eclipse 2022-03 installation to see if the problem appears there as well or is specific to the STS 4.14.0.RELEASE install - and probably file a bug with Infinitest about this.

Comment: Problem also exists in Eclipse 2022-03l; looks like there are already issues reported there

Comment: Can you post the link to the issue that you found? Might be helpful for others when stumbling upon this problem.

Comment: issues with infinitest Eclipse preferences at https://github.com/infinitest/infinitest/issues/289

Comment: This should be fixed with the latest version, a few old dependencies have been upgraded to allow compatibility with newer versions of java and eclipse